# Set default value of all columns runtime in DataGridView

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview

I am adding n Numbers of columns on a datagridview. The number of columns is not fixed and also the name of column is fixed. Also i want to add deault value for all columns in every rows like
[image: datgrid view]

Also these columns are added on runtime and datasource of gird is also associate with a class

```
       DbDataEntities db = new DbDataEntities();


var MasterAttendanceTypesDetail = db.MasterAttendanceTypes.ToList();
            foreach (string AttendanceType in MasterAttendanceTypesDetail.Select(s => s.AttendanceTypeName).ToList())
            {
                if (!dgv1.Columns.Contains(AttendanceType))
                {
                    DataGridViewColumn dgchkCol = new DataGridViewColumn();
                    dgchkCol.Name = AttendanceType;
                    dgv1.Columns.Add(dgchkCol);
                }
            }
```

Number of columns added in grid is depend on number of entries in tabel at it is almost 100.
thus how could i set default value of each column.

Comment: Are you databinding this grid to an entity?

If yes you might want to implement defaulting at the entity level and not as something specific to the interface.  You might be adding business rules in your GUI that belong in a business layer.

Comment: yes i am doing this from entity ..  but how could i add business rule can you please tell me or provide a link for yhis

Comment: I've added an answer below...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can inherit the DataGridViewColumn and DataGridViewCell and override the **DefaultNewRowValue** property.

```
public class ExtendedColumn : DataGridViewColumn
{
    public ExtendedColumn()
        : base(new ExtendedCell())
    {
    }
}

public class ExtendedCell : DataGridViewTextBoxCell
{
    public ExtendedCell()
        : base()
    {
    }

    public override object DefaultNewRowValue
    {
        get
        {
            return "aaa";
        }
    }
}
```

And use it in your code like this:

```
ExtendedColumn col = new ExtendedColumn();
col.Name = AttendanceType;
dgv1.Columns.Add(col);
```

Here is a link to MSDN that demonstrates the use of DefaultNewRowValue:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcell.defaultnewrowvalue(v=vs.110).aspx

But since you can have many columns for which default value is required, you can handle **DefaultValuesNeeded** event.

```
dataGridView1.DefaultValuesNeeded +=new DataGridViewRowEventHandler(dataGridView1_DefaultValuesNeeded);

private void dataGridView1_DefaultValuesNeeded(object sender,
System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Row.Cells[0].Value = "aaa";
        e.Row.Cells[1].Value = "bbb";
        e.Row.Cells[2].Value = "ccc";

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This would be my approach if the data was not already bound to a DataSet. Binding the data to a table allows you to to create constraints and other rules on the table itself rather than messing with the grid control.

Also, it lets you easily export the data to wherever you want once the data entry is complete. You could pass the data into `GetTable` function however you want. I just built sample data into a 2-dimensional array for demonstration.

I strongly recommend you consider adding rows to the table programmatically as well. The control is intended to be used with ADO.NET.

```
    private void BuildDataGrid() {
        //--------------------------------------------------
        // Create list of test column names and default 
        // values
        //--------------------------------------------------
        string[,] columns = new string[50,2];

        for (int n = 0; n < 50; n++) {
            columns[n, 0] = "column_" + n.ToString();
            columns[n, 1] = "def" + n.ToString();
        }

        //--------------------------------------------------
        // Bind table to grid
        //--------------------------------------------------
        m_dataGridView.DataSource = GetTable(columns);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Create a table from the raw data.
    /// </summary>
    private DataTable GetTable(string[,] columns) {

        DataTable table = new DataTable();

        for (int n = 0; n < columns.GetLength(0); n++) {
            DataColumn column = new DataColumn(columns[n, 0], typeof(string)) {
                DefaultValue = columns[n, 1]
            };

            table.Columns.Add(column);
        }

        return table;
    }
```

Comment: BTW. This is how you add rows.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z16c79x4(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Manually Add Column

```
       for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++)
        {
            dataGridView1.Columns.Add("Column" + i, "Column"+i);
        }
```

Manually Add Rows

```
dataGridView1.Rows.Add(10);
```

Manually Add Value in Datagridview

```
            for (int i = 0; i <= dataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j <= dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; j++)
                {
                    dataGridView1.Rows[j].Cells[i].Value = "aaa";
                }
            }
```

Comment: It takes lots of time adding column manually and set there values is there is not any way to which i do it directly

Comment: but there is large numbers of rows

Comment: if your table have no value first pass value in your table otherwise not possible

Answer (score 0):

Create new class that is delivered from DataGridViewCell. Override DefaultNewRowValue to return the default value that you want(you can pass this as constructor parameter).
After creating your column set dgchkCol.CellTemplate to a new instance of your custom DataGridViewCell implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Get GridView count then iterate with:

```
for (int i = 0; i <=DS.Tables[0].Rows.Count;; i++)
{
row[i].Cell[0].FindControl("txtTextBox1").Value="aaa";
row[i].Cell[1].FindControl("txtTextBox2").Value="bbb";
row[i].Cell[2].FindControl("txtTextBox3").Value="ccc";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the datagrid is being bound to a collection of Entity Framework entities you could do your initialization at the entity level.

You can do this by creating a partial class and declaring a constructor for the entity.

e.g. If I have an entity tblUser

```
partial class tblUser
{
    public tblUser()
    {
        Surname = "Smith";
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        TestEntities test = new TestEntities();
        var user = test.tblUsers.CreateObject();

        Console.WriteLine(user.Surname);
        // Prints Smith
    }
}
```