# ComboBox DataSource C#

Tags: c#, datagridview, enums

I have a DataGridView with some columns, one of them is a DataGridViewTextBoxColumn (x:name = ColumnTypeSpeed).
When I start the program I do the following :

```
ColumnTypeSpeed.DataSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof(BusSpeed));
```

"BusSpeed" is my enum :

```
 public enum BusSpeed
        {
            BR_125000 = 125000,
            BR_666666 = 666666,
            BR_33333 = 33333,
            BR_50000 = 50000,
            BR_62500 = 62500,
            BR_100000 = 100000,
            BR_250000 = 250000,
            BR_500000 = 500000,
            BR_1000000 = 1000000

        }
```

The default item is ever the first in the enum list(BR_125000), How do I select another item as default by code ?

Comment: In the future please be careful when selecting language tags. C and C# are not the same.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set default value of all columns runtime in DataGridView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20240512/set-default-value-of-all-columns-runtime-in-datagridview)

Answer (score 0):

Just override the DefaultNewRowValue property.

```
public class ExtendedCell : DataGridViewTextBoxCell 
{

   public ExtendedCell(): base()
   {

   }

public override object DefaultNewRowValue
{
    get
    {
        return "aaa";
    }
}

ExtendedColumn col = new ExtendedColumn();
col.Name = AttendanceType;
dgv1.Columns.Add(col);
```

Got it from here [Set default value of all columns runtime in DataGridView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20240512/set-default-value-of-all-columns-runtime-in-datagridview)